# Recreate the SQL*PLUS Show command (sga and parameter) in SQL for Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle-apex

As it says in the title i want to populate an Apex report based on the information from:

```
show sga
show parameter
```

commands that exist in sql plus

Does anyone know the select statements that go on in the backround for this or what tables it references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show parameter can be simulated through this select:

```
select name,  
       case type 
         when 1 then 'boolean'  
         when 2 then 'string' 
         when 3 then 'integer' 
         when 4 then 'parameter file' 
         when 5 then 'reserved' 
         when 6 then 'big integer' 
         else to_char(type) 
       end as type,  
       value, 
       description, 
       update_comment 
from v$parameter 
where name like '%foo%'
```

Show SGA can be simulated using this statement:

```
select 'Total System Global Area' as "Memory", 
       sum(VALUE) as "Value", 
       'bytes' as unit 
from V$SGA 
union all 
select NAME, 
       VALUE, 
       'bytes' 
from V$SGA
```